# automatic storage class variable in C declared outside the function block

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function1(void);
auto int z = 10;

int main()
{
printf("Hello, I'm main.\n");
}

void function1(void)
{
printf("Hello, I'm function1.\n");
}
```

- Variable 'z' is declared outside the function blocks, and belongs to
  'automatic storage class'.
- **Variable 'z' is part of which function block in this scenario?**
- **What are the properties of the variable 'z' in this scenario?**

Comment: Did you try to run that by a compiler before asking if the code makes any sense?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes.

Comment: And you got no errors? Now I'm curious. What compiler did you use?

Comment: This is a good question, to my mind. But "it compiles" does not mean that the program is correct. You should always look for warnings (and enable mostly all of them with `-Wall` and maybe `-Wextra`). Btw it does not compile with gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: @StoryTeller I got an error, the program didn't compile. But i was curious to know about the ownership of the variable.

Comment: It compiles with the Microsoft C compiler provided with Visual Studio 2017, but you get the warning: `Warning C4042 z : has bad storage class"`, in that case the `auto` keyword is probably ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @ShaikNisarAhmed _I got an error, the program didn't compile_. If the program didn't compile it's pointless to discuss about the ownership of the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Code contains *constraint violation* and is not valid C code. This means that there is no guarantee that your code will compile or work correctly.

> ### 6.9 External definitions
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 2. The storage-class specifiers `auto` and `register` shall not appear in the declaration specifiers in an
>      external declaration.

So answers to your questions are:

- Variable is not part of any function block, since it's external declaration.
- Properties of the variable `z` are undefined, because the code is invalid.